# Search in Laravel Datatables

Tags: laravel, datatables

In my datatables, the search function works only on the name column. The name column ist different that the others. It means, the name column gives the value of the database back, while the others gives a value back with the function add column

In the column array there are the following values:

````
´´´
        protected function getColumns()
   {
    return [
        'status',
        'name' => [
            'title' => 'Name',
            'orderable' => true,
            'searchable' => true
        ],
        'location' => [
            'title' => 'Standort',

        ],
        'department' => [
            'title' => 'Abteilung',
            'orderable' => true,
            'searchable' => true
        ],
        'division' => [
            'title' => 'Bereich',
            'orderable' => true,
            'searchable' => true
        ],
        'leader' => [
            'title' => 'Verantwortlicher',
            'orderable' => true,
            'searchable' => true
        ],
        'start_date' => [
            'title' => 'Startdatum',
            'searchable'=> true,
        ],
        'end_date' => [
            'title' => 'Enddatum',
            'searchable'=> true
        ]
    ];
   }
 ```
````

Why it doesn't search on all columns? What i have to do?

Comment: Are you using some sort of package to render your DataTables? Or how do you use this array?

Comment: I'm using Yajra Datatables

Comment: [This](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/139)  should answer your question.

Comment: I don't find the way. What is the right code to filter the column like this one: ```           ->addColumn('location', function(Project $project) {
                return $project->location->name;
            })```

Comment: can anybody help?

Comment: I thought by default Datatables were searchable.  Try taking out 'searchable' => true on them all and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to search by using this code.

```
return Datatables::of($tasks)
->filter(function ($query) use ($request) {
    $title = $request->title;
    if (isset($title) && !empty($title)) {
        $query->where('title', 'like', '%'.$title.'%');
    }
})->make(true);
```

OR

```
return Datatables::of($tasks)
->filterColumn('title', function($query, $value) {
    $query->whereRaw("title like ?", ["%{$value}%"]);
})->make(true);
```